# ViewPager image gallery loading

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ListView with item's. Each item is ViewPager.
In ViewPager I pass PagerAdapter with array of image urls.
Because of such design there are to many images loading at the same time.
How to not start image loading of all viewpager items before swipe action?
I want my app to start loading only the image from the first page..

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the current code it's hard to give a precise solution. But the general idea would be:

1. Do not load all images at startup.
2. Attach a [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) to each of the ViewPagers.
3. When a new page is reached (`onPageSelected()`), load the image that goes in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) ViewPager.setOffscrenPageLimit(1)

and if you are using Fragments, you should load your image in the method onStart() or onResume()